# Resume bookmark against workflow service

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

I'm using WF4 and have a workflow service in which I have created a custom activity that creates a bookmark to wait for additional user input.  When hosting the workflow with a WorkflowApplication I can simply call ResumeBookmark to pick up processing where I left off but I can't seem to figure out how to resume a bookmark when the workflow is being hosted as a Workflow Service.

Any guidance would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to create an activity extension implementing the IWorkflowInstanceExtension interface and use the BeginResumeBookmark()/EndResumeBookmark() functions provided by the WorkflowInstanceProxy. See [here](http://msmvps.com/blogs/theproblemsolver/archive/2010/01/27/using-wf4-bookmarks-with-iworkflowinstanceextension.aspx) for a simple example.

Comment: I read the post but I'm not clear on how the client application calls the WorkflowServiceHost to resume the bookmark.  Can you please explain that?  My solution is made up of 2 projects, one for the client and another for the workflow service.

Comment: If you client class into the service I recommend you go with the WCF integration layer and use the Receive and SendReply activities. Makes live a lot easier.

Comment: I hadn't realized that the Receive activities could be used like bookmarks.  I was able to give them all the same OperationName so my client app can just call that operation and the workflow figures out where it left off.  Thanks Maurice!

Comment: Internally all async activities like Receive, ReceiveResonse and Delay use bookmarks to pause workflow execution.

Comment: Maurice: How I can resume a suspended WCF workflow service , which is persisted , by using a client web site which uses the WCF workflow service?